# CONFLICT during GIT interactive rebase

Tags: git, merge, repository, commit, rebase

I am no expert with Git and had started recently to use `git rebase -i` for squashing multiple pushed commits in my C project into one. This is indeed nice for cleaning up the branch history after a fix has been implemented and tested.

Today i'm struggling however. I made multiple commits to solve an issue and trying to squash the commits into just one. Some of my changes however involved renaming source files.

I do git `rebase -i HEAD~5` to attempt to squash the five previous commits into one. When the editor pops up, I leave the oldest commit at **"picked"** and put **"s"** on the others to squash.

I have all sorts of conflicts and the rebase cannot happen, such as :

`CONFLICT (rename/delete): src/myfile.c deleted in HEAD and renamed to src/mynewfile.c`

and

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/test.c
```

Is there a way to simply have my latest commit as the one I want (of course the combination of all the last five commits), and avoid all this conflict resolving mess manually? Otherwise I don't see too much point in the rebase option. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it non possible to merge each commit one by one?

Comment: How is it related to C? Do not spam tags

Comment: @Irelia I'm not sure?

Comment: In general, this kind of rebase-to-squash works fine *unless* there is a merge operation within the set of commits that you're rebasing like this. Since you didn't show the output of `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` before the rebase, I can't say for sure that this is the problem, but that's my guess. In any case [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72958844/1256452) gives you a way to entirely bypass the whole rebase process.

Answer (score 0):

The easiedt way to squash is with a reset soft. Say your branch is 5 revisions (assuming straight revisions, no merges):

```
git checkout my-branch
git reset --soft @~5
git commit -m "all my changes in a single revision"
```

And that's it.